# How to save a value to a variable in a form

Tags: php, html, sql

How to save a value to a global variable in a form.
Form code:

```
<form method='GET'  action='11.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $value["product_id"];  ?>'   >
  <input type='hidden' name='id'value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
<td><input type='hidden' name='pname'value="<?php echo $row['pname']; ?>" /> 
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity'value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>" /> 
    <input type='hidden' name='price'value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" /> 


<a href="11.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $value['product_id'];?>">
<span class="text-danger" ><b style="color:white; " >Remove</span></a>

</tr>
    <?php 
    $total=$total+($value["item_quantity"] * $value["product_price"]);  }
    ?>  
  </form>
```

I need to save to variable "a", the value "$value['product_id']".
Just trying to assign a value a= "$value['product_id']".
I can't. Little experience.

C variable all clear. Now there was another question with the removal.
I have a delete event, when I click delete, it deletes from the shopping cart, but it does not delete from the database (mysql). Probably, I incorrectly affix WHERE id = '$ id'. Here is a part of the code to delete.
......

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])){
            if($_GET["action"]=="delete"){
                foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $key=>$value){
                    if($value["product_id"]==$_GET["id"]){
                        unset($_SESSION["cart"][$key]);
```

.........

```
Connection ….
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

if (isset($_GET["action"])){
if($_GET["action"]=="delete")
{
$sql = "DELETE FROM products9 WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;}}}
```

Comment: Where do you do this? There is no variable `$a` in your code. And what do you mean by "I can't"? What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Me If I Wrong ...

```
<?php 
    $a = $_GET["id"];
?>
```

If use form **method='GET'**, then u should get variable data from 
`action='11.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $value["product_id"]; ?>'`, for this case you need assign variable **a** to  `$value["product_id"]` from GET method, you should get variable from `id=<?php echo $value["product_id"];?>`.  but if you use form **method='POST'** then u should get variable data from your input name. such as `$_POST["pname"]`.

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from your code?

Comment: more u can visit [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain why you read that value from `$_GET["id"]` while that variable should contain the product ID - as the form contains two values for `id`, there might be problems in reading that data